# JScrollPane holding a JPanel is buggy

Tags: java, swing

Recently I started making a Map Editor for my game and I came across a couple of issues that I've kind of have fixed. My current problem right now is that I have a JFrame (main interface). Within that JFrame I have a JScrollPane which holds my Client(a JPanel). Since I can't post picture I will post a link of the image.
Image of GUI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd1Pu.png

This is where I add my client(JPanel) to the JScrollPane.

```
//======== mainScrollPane ========
        {
            client.setPreferredSize(client.getSize());
            mainScrollPane.setPreferredSize(client.getSize());
            mainScrollPane.setViewportView(client);
            mainScrollPane.add(client);
```

This is my Client.java|The MapEditor class is a little large to post here but feel free to ask for snippets or anymore information.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Client extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Thread animationThread;
    protected Map map;
    private Tile tile;
    public int mX, mY;

    public Client() {
        init();
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        animationThread = new Thread(this);
        animationThread.start();
    }

    public void init() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        ImageHandler.loadImages();
        map = new Map();
        setSize(1000, 500);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (animationThread != null) {
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
        map.drawCurrentMap(gg);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
        //final Point p = e.getPoint();
        //final int x = p.x / 25;
        //final int y = p.y / 25;
        //map.getTileAt(x, y).setGraphicId(MapEditor.id);
        //map.getTileAt(x, y).setBlocked(true);
        map.getTiles().set(map.getTileIndex(mX, mY), new Tile(mX, mY, true, MapEditor.id));
        System.out.println(map.getTiles().get(map.getTileIndex(mX, mY)).toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {;

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mX = e.getX()/25;
        mY = e.getY()/25;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with scroll pane, but with how you've done your custom painting...

Basically, this...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
    map.drawCurrentMap(gg);
}
```

Is breaking the paint chain requirements.  A `Graphics` context is a shared resource, meaning that everything painting within a given paint cycle shares the same `Graphics` contents.

Painting is also a complex chain of methods which is, as you've discovered, really easy to break.

Instead, you should override `paintComponent` and perform your custom painting there, making sure you call `super.paintComponent` first

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you for your answer! See, I didn't know that. I always thought I could just use paint() anywhere. I didn't know JPanel came packed with paintComponent.
This is how my pain looks like now. Is that how you wanted me to change it ?
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
     map.drawCurrentMap(gg);
 }

Comment: Yep, but I make `paintComponent` `protected`, there's no reason for anybody else to calling your method ;)